# How can $(window).unload be executed without closing window/tab

Tags: jquery

I have a very strange phenomenon that is try to understand how it happens.

I use **jQuery 1.7.1** and in my code I use `$(window).unload` to tigger a SQL-statement to record that the user now has closed the browser. With it I do a series of updates and all seems to work just fine. Problem is that apparently sometimes the function `unload()` is fired even if the browser/tab has **not** been closed and that causes some severe problems.

Anyone that know something about this - mainly how such thing can happen?
One crazy theory we had was that some browers might go in some hibernation after a while if you haven't the tab highlighted but I haven't found any proof of this online.

If I want to use another function in its stead, are there better once within the same jQuery version?

EDIT: Missed a very important not in my text.

Comment: `sometimes the function unload() is fired even if the browser/tab has been closed` Are you sure? Possibly there is a second tab/window open that is sending the same data (from shared local storage or cookies) or some more simple explanation.

Comment: That sentence really didn't make much sense did it? I see a not that are missing. Editing.

Comment: Did you check out the MDN reference for that event? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unload - to me this reads like it's something in your implementation. Please put some code in your question &/or link to a fiddle and I'll take a look.